# Windows 8 File Access and the ms-appx:/// protocol

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

Is it possible to access files(e.g. images, audio and videos) in Windows 8 C# without using the "ms-appx:///" protocol?

Answer (score 5):

If you are accessing the end user's images/etc., you can do it without ms-appx like this (where file is of type StorageFile):

```
var fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
img.SetSource(fileStream);
```

If you are including images/etc. in your application, then you can use the ms-appx protocol.  It essentially means "get this from the app package".  But you can also use a relative path.  See [this article on how to load file resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh965322%28v=win.10%29.aspx).